# How to draw dendrogram using ape package in R?

Tags: r, dendrogram, ape-phylo

I have a distance matrix of ~200 x 200 size I an unable to plot a dendrogram using the BioNJ option of ape library in R
The size is big to make the plot visible 
What ways can I improve the visibility[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options depending on your data

If you need to calculate the distance matrix of your data then use

```
set.seed(1)                          # makes random sampling with rnorm reproducible
# example matrix
m <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 5)    # any MxN matrix
distm <- dist(m)                     # distance matrix
hm <- hclust(distm)
plot(hm)
```

If your data is a distance matrix (must be a square matrix!)

```
set.seed(1)
# example matrix
m <- matrix(rnorm(25), nrow=5)       # must be square matrix!
distm <- as.dist(m)
hm <- hclust(distm)
plot(hm)
```

A 200 x 200 distance matrix gives me a reasonable plot

```
set.seed(1)
# example matrix
m <- matrix(rnorm(200*200), nrow=200)       # must be square matrix!
distm <- as.dist(m)
hm <- hclust(distm)
plot(hm)
```

Comment: While using clustering also the plot looks like a clubbed mass I am unable to identify the any pattern out of it my square matrix size is 200 X 200

Comment: Can you try plotting the 200x200 distance matrix at the bottom. What do you get?

Comment: @LakshmiKrishnaKumaar did you try the plot at the bottom of my answer?

Comment: thanks for the answer but trying plot also gives a similar plot I am checking with the data once